# How can I save photos that I take with my Android's camera in a lossless format?

Tags: camera, images, photos

How can I save the images captured with my Android's camera in RAW or TIFF format?  Are there any apps, ROM/kernel Modifications or other methods that will allow me to accomplish this?

Technically I need to be able to save the RAW data or at least save them as TIFFs <s>however I am also open saving them as PNGs if RAW and TIFF are out of the question</s>.  Converting the natively saved jpegs to TIFF <s>or PNG</s> is not a suitable option for me.

I have seen [this question that states that RAW is not possible](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13916/is-there-any-way-to-save-a-raw-image-from-my-phones-camera), however it is over a year old and I'm hoping something may have changed.  I'm also broadening the scope to include other "lossless" options.

I'm currently using a vzw version of the GS3 that is rooted and running a custom ROM.  I regularly use the built in camera, [Camera Zoom FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom) and [Camera 360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360) and none of these seem to be capable of saving lossless images.

**UPDATE:**  I just found out that PNG does not save EXIF information so it is no longer a suitable option.

Comment: I think, that converting JPGs to TIFFs is not an option for anyone! :> Anyway, there is a small (very small and unconfirmed) chance that any _real camera with Android_ (like [Samsung Galaxy Camera](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/galaxy-camera/galaxy-camera/EK-GC100ZWABTU) will have "something around RAW or lossless photos". But, since it is still based on Android, ZnewmaN's answers will probably be valid. Chances, that you're going to get it on GS3 or any other _phone with camera on board_ are even smaller (for below mentioned resons).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking raw photos using Android devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48880/taking-raw-photos-using-android-devices) (the answer on that question is more updated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The camera api within android is not written to be able to capture RAW. The camera firmware is at the kernel level and would require a custom kernel that is written with RAW in mind. Some of the post processing is being handled on the phone at the camera firmware level making it nearly impossible to find a way to actually capture RAW images.