# Taking raw photos using Android devices

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. Is there a way in Android or an app that can take [raw photos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format)? I.e. have the raw camera data to process in a program like Photoshop. I am using Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Related: [RAW camera and Lollipop](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109106/raw-camera-and-lollipop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, there is no public API that allows developers to create camera apps that takes raw photos. Based on what I've read in dpreview.com, implementation would have to be at driver level, and specific to each device.

Also, raw files taken by camera phones would also look *nasty*.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Quite an education and a disappointment. While majority of phone would look nasty there are some newer models like the Nokia EOS (I know, not an android phone) and the Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom that take nice photos.

Comment: @Lynda Yes, I think think some Nokia phones support raw format (DNG).

Comment: @geffchang Not yet, but they will. Check here: http://www.engadget.com/2013/10/22/nokia-bringing-raw-imaging-lumia-1520-and-1020/

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

Now it's possible to take raw photos on some Lollipop devices, like Nexus 6 and 5, among others.

Why is this possible? Because Lollipop includes a lot of new APIs to work with the camera (Camera APIs v2), so any developer today can use them and take the most of the device camera.

Nowadays, Camera FV-5 is the best app to do this (although it is compatible with older versions of Android, raw format only works on Lollipop devices). You can [try it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.lite) or [buy it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.pro&hl=es_419).

**Note**: Raw capture only works on paid version.

[This is another useful link](http://www.cnet.com/news/android-lollipop-opens-high-end-photography-options/)!