# How to make it possible to save raw photos on Samsung Galaxy A3 2017?

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-a3

I have a rooted Galaxy A3 2017 (SM-A320F) running Android 8.0.0. I'm trying to capture raw photos, but neither the stock Camera app nor Open Camera show any relevant options (I have enabled Camera2 API). This option wasn't present before rooting too. On another phone, unrooted Galaxy Note8, the option is present at least in Open Camera.

So I suppose the option is somehow disabled in my A3. Can it be re-enabled without switching to a completely different firmware? How?

Note that [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/48880/121876) proposed as a duplicate is 1) asking about very old version of Android — 4.2.2, which doesn't have Camera2 API, and 2) asks simply whether there exist any apps with such functionality, which today is of course *yes*. So this one is not a duplicate. This question is about *how to re-enable the missing raw photo support* instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking raw photos using Android devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48880/taking-raw-photos-using-android-devices)

Comment: @Zackary it's not, see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to already be possible, with the stock firmware! I was about to try tracing an NDK-powered camera app (thanks to [Sisik's tutorial with a demo](https://sisik.eu/blog/android/ndk/camera)) with `strace` to see which API calls lead to which `ioctl`s to aid further searches, when, while trimming down the demo, I noticed that the native camera API exposes `AIMAGE_FORMAT_RAW16` with dimensions 4144×3106 on my Galaxy SM-A320F/DS. After I went ahead and tried capturing an image in this format, I indeed got a true 16-bit Bayer output, which after simplistic demosaicing and white-balancing resulted in a pretty decent raw image.

There's a small strangeness though: the bottom part of the image (pixels 2333 through 3106) is always filled with zeros. I'm not sure why this is so, but at least the upper 75% of the data are present and usable.

**How to get RAW support in OpenCamera**

Currently, OpenCamera detects whether a camera supports RAW by `REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_RAW`. If there's no such capability, the detection simply gives negative result. For SM-A320F this is incorrect, because it doesn't report this capability, but RAW16 format is among the supported output formats.

To work around this misdetection, we can apply the following patch to OpenCamera 1.47.3, and build our own APK. This patch will stub out the check for the capability, making OpenCamera search for the format desired regardless.

```
diff --git a/app/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/opencamera/cameracontroller/CameraController2.java b/app/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/opencamera/cameracontroller/CameraController2.java
index 2c6463c..939b00b 100644
--- a/app/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/opencamera/cameracontroller/CameraController2.java
+++ b/app/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/opencamera/cameracontroller/CameraController2.java
@@ -2062,7 +2062,7 @@ public class CameraController2 extends CameraController {
         //camera_features.picture_sizes.get(0).supports_burst = false;

         raw_size = null;
-        if( capabilities_raw ) {
+        if( true || capabilities_raw ) {
             android.util.Size [] raw_camera_picture_sizes = configs.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR);
             if( raw_camera_picture_sizes == null ) {
                 if( MyDebug.LOG )
```

I've reported this at OpenCamera's issue tracker as [ticket 661](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/tickets/661/).

Answer (score 1):

Camera2 API alone doesn't necessarily mean you can shoot RAW, though you can run the free app [Manual Camera Compatibility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.vipek.camera2_compatibility_test). If it shows that your phone supports RAW, you should be able to shoot RAW with the [Manual Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.vipek.camera2) app itself.

[Photoshop Lightroom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.lrmobile&hl=de) is another app capable of capturing and editing RAW, so maybe that's worth a shot aswell.

Comment: Lightroom also doesn't work, which is unsurprising, given that the capability is not exposed via the API. And Manual Camera simply lies, saying that the device supports raw shooting (see also its reviews). Of course, I'm not going to buy it simply to find out that it doesn't work.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know the Manual Camera test lied, I had phones showing incompatibility on it earlier. What is the output of [this app?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.weis.camera2probe&hl=de) That developer doesn't have any camera app to sell so maybe that app is more truthful.

Comment: Oh, nevermind me, I just saw your edit. So you're already aware that your device's HAL3 doesn't do RAW at all which is nothing you can do about sadly. This would be up to the phone manufacturer to do.

Comment: The _Camera2 probe_ app does confirm that raw capture is not available. This one looks much more reliable. The question of how to re-enable raw support remains...

Comment: You can't just re-enable RAW support yourself or by flashing a custom firmware or ROM. Try contacting the manufacturer for a solution as only they are able to provide you with that functionality. This comes down to hardware level drivers, Camera2 API is only an interface to use available functions like RAW. Even while your camera sensor (Sony IMX 258) might be perfectly capable, if the manufacturer decided not to include RAW support, sadly, you're out of luck here.

Comment: If the manufacturer decided to provide me with this functionality, how could they do this if you claim that flashing another firmware won't work?

Comment: I said custom firmware, there are plenty of communities modding and customizing all sorts of firmwares and operating systems. Still, you won't find a custom firmware (feel free to search XDA, the largest community of those) that enables RAW support, that was what I am saying.

Comment: If the manufacturer decides to provide you with an updated image that enables support, of course you would have to flash it. I apologize for my poor wording.