# Does android Support RAW image capturing?

Tags: camera, photos

I'd like to capture RAW images from my Droid Camera rather than those compressed jpg's, is there anyway to achieve this?

EDIT: I saw that it's **not** possible due to kernel limitation, **but**, what kind of limitation? Do i need to load a kernel module? or the kernel must be modified and re-built from scratch? Is there **ANY** way to achieve this? i can **chroot** Ubuntu, i can load Kernel Modules, i will do everything just to achieve this

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Is there any way to save a raw image from my phone's camera?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13916/981), [How can I save photos that I take with my Android's camera in a lossless format?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32118/981). I think this is something that may be in the Android L camera API: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8274/understanding-androids-camera-hal3

Comment: @eldarerathis oh, i've been searching for around an Hour for some answers but i didn't able to find anything, how i didn't come a cross them, ahh..